# Understanding Weierstrass’ decomposition formula.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[This](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9Fsche_Zerlegungsformel#cite_ref-1) is the only article or resource I can find on Weierstrass’ decomposition formula which can be read in English.

That Wikipedia article writes

> It [Weierstrass decomposition formula) breaks down values of differentiable functions into two summands: first, the value of the tangent function of the output function with respect to a point in the domain of definition, and second, the remainder or the error of the linear approximation.

Can someone please explain me what’s the tangent function and error function?

Is Weierstrass decomposition formula something similar to that “secant becoming tangent” approach that we use to explain the concept of derivates to beginners in Calculus?

Comment: Your link goes to a *German* Wikipedia page.

Comment: @MartinR Google chrome can translate it to English.  There is no other resource that I could find which could be read in English.

Comment: I can read it :) – Note that this “formula” is the essentially  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem for $k=1$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh I didn’t see that you’re from Deutschland. Actually, I need to use Weierstrass’ decomposition formula for defining derivatives, but Taylor series is already using it.

Comment: That  article makes things look more complicated than they are, IMO. What it says is that a function $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ if and only if there is a number $c$ and a function $r$ such that $f(x) = f(x_0) + c(x-x_0) + (x-x_0)r(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} r(x) = 0$, and in that case is $c = f'(x_0)$. $f(x_0) + c(x-x_0)$ is the “tangent function” and $(x-x_0)r(x)$ is the “error function.”

Comment: @MartinR That was a good explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinR : Why not post your comment as an answer? Then it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @JohnBentin: Done :)

Comment: The benefit of Weierstrass's characterization is that it generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$, where it is the definition of differentiability. See the Frechet derivative.

Comment: @Mason My aim was not to go for higher dimensions. I was doing a kind of research on definitions of limits and derivatives, and got to know that Weierstraß didn’t use epsilontic definition of limits for defining derivatives.

Comment: I got to know that Weierstrass didn’t actually used the geometric concept of secants and tangents for his decomposition, yet his decomposition formula can be explained using those geometric constructions. Any further information will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ to simplify the notation. The formula states that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if there is a “decomposition” $f(x) = t(x)+R(x)$ where

1. a linear function $t(x) = f(x_0) + c(x-x_0)$, and
2. an “error function” $R(x) = (x-x_0)r(x)$ with $\lim_{x \to x_0} r(x) = 0$.

In that case is $c = f'(x_0)$ and $t$ is the tangent at the graph of $f$ at $(x_0, f(x_0))$.

Figuratively speaking: $f$ can be linearly approximated with an error term that vanishes “of higher than linear order” at $x_0$.

The above equivalence follows directly from the definition of the derivative. Alternatively, one can use it as a definition: $f'(x_0) := c$ if there is a “Weierstraß decomposition” satisfying (1) and (2).